# Is it possible to query within a JTable renderer?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jtable

I'm trying to do a table that can be in differents colors each cell depending the dates that i bring from mysql, the problem is, when i tried to bring the dates from the query inside the new renderer the program run so slow until it crashed and netbenas show me a lot of messenges "connection successful" and then "Connection closed" and thats because it conects a lot of time to mysql.

I need help here´s my renderer code

```
public class MiRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus,
            int row,
            int column) {





        cell = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if (!mes.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("All")) {
            tabla.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_NEXT_COLUMN);

        } else {
            tabla.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        }

        tabla.setRowHeight(26);



        if (column == 0) {
            tabla.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
            tabla.setEnabled(false);

        } else {
            tabla.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
            tabla.setEnabled(true);
        }
        tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(tabla.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer());

        DataBase db = new DataBase();
    ResultSet /*Dudas de variable ResultSet se encuentran en línea 207 de EVR_Main*/ rs;
    rs = db.getRecords( /*Ver funciones de método getRecords en línea 192 de EVR_Main*/
            "SELECT Start_Date, End_Date, idmae, State FROM Capacity ");


    try {
        rs.beforeFirst();
        while (rs.next()) {



        if (isSelected) {
            tabla.setRowSelectionInterval(tabla.getSelectedRow(), tabla.getSelectedRow());

            cell.setBackground(new Color(colo));
            cell.setForeground(Color.black);
            cell.setOpaque(true);
            cell.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));

        } else if (rs.getDate(1)== lastdate) {

            cell.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            cell.setForeground(Color.blue);
            cell.setOpaque(true);
            cell.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));

        } else {
            // Restaurar los valores por defecto
            cell.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            cell.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            cell.setOpaque(true);
            cell.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));

        }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Capacity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    db.closeConnection();

        return this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing the SQL query within the table cell renderer. This is completely wrong. Consider that the renderer is working one cell at a time, this means the query will be performed for each and every rendered cell, which can happen very frequently. Thus the rendering will be excessively slow. Since it happens in the AWT event thread, this will cause the entire UI to look effectively frozen.

You need to redesign your code such that the query is performed outside the renderer and much less frequently, and store the fields of the query results in a separate data structure, for instance a list or an array of value objects, each VO representing a table row from the query.

Then you need to be able to correlate each of these objects with locations in the JTable (row and/or column coordinates) or at least with the `value` parameter sent as input to the cell renderer. This is normally done by using an appropriate table model.

All of these concepts are illustrated in the [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) section of the Swing tutorial, and I invite you to take a good look at it.